# get last 12 months dates in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a custom month picker where it gives a list of last 12 months

Like its Auguest so it should return list of dates like

Aug 2023,July 2023,June 2023, May 2023,.........sept 2022

i have created a UDF as following but missing how to deduct a month

```
List<DateTime> getMonths() {
    
    final dates = <DateTime>[];
    final now = DateTime.now();
    
    int number_of_months=DateTime.now().month+12;
    
    DateTime date=DateTime.now();
    for(int x=0;x<number_of_months;x++)
      {
        dates.add(date);


       date=??? //how to deduct one month here from date
      }
    
    

        return dates;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a new DateTime with deducted month, you can do as

```
List<DateTime> getLast12Months() {
    List<DateTime> dates = [];
    final today = DateTime.now();
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
      dates.add(DateTime(today.year, today.month - x, 1));
    }
    return dates;
  }
```

Here, as you can see in the for loop, we are just deducting the loop value from the month in `today` date and creating a new `DateTime`

You will get output as following:

```
[
   2023-08-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-07-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-06-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-05-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-04-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-03-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-02-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2023-01-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2022-12-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2022-11-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2022-10-01 00:00:00.000, 
   2022-09-01 00:00:00.000
]
```

You can use [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to format the date as per your need.

Comment: if i use format from intl..it will return list<String> right? how to keep return time same and it should return in Aug 2023, July 2023..... can u pls implement my code with use of intl....dont change return type

Comment: As you said, Intl returns string-type data. So, either you have to change the return type or convert it to string only when you display it in the widget